# lxc-stop says container-name not running, when it is running

Tags: lxc

I've created a container using `lxc launch ubuntu:16.04`. My host machine is ubuntu 16.04 as well. The container is running:

[image]

But when I run `lxc-stop` like this:

```
» lxc-stop ideal-bluejay
```

I get the output

> ideal-bluejay is not running

I think this could be because I used `newgrp lxd` after adding myself to `lxd` group instead of just logging out and back in again while following [ubuntu's lxd guide](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-setting-up-lxd-1604#1)

I've since logged in and out, and even rebooted the computer. I was able to stop two previously-running containers (surprisingly, they were still running after the reboot, there might be some default checkpointing-and-restore going on). But I'm not able to stop this container which I just launched in this session.

---

Additional Info: In case if using lxc without logging out after adding myself to lxd group is indeed a problem, then it may help to knowthat I'm not able to destroy the stopped containers either.

On running

```
» lxc-destroy valid-anemone
```

I get the output

> ```
> lxc-destroy: conf.c: userns_exec_full: 4163 No mapping for container root found
> lxc-destroy: lxccontainer.c: container_destroy: 2707 Error destroying container directory for valid-anemone
> Destroying valid-anemone failed
> ```

Comment: note: "lxc-stop" (LXC) is not "lxc stop" (LXD), perhaps they aren't using the same default environment.

Comment: @A.B wow, that was indeed the issue. Trying this would've been the last thing on my mind. Please post this as an answer so that I can accept it!

Comment: While I know quite some stuff about LXC, I don't know much about LXD. I'd prefer to put an answer describing how each handles its configuration, but I'm not up to do this for LXD. I don't mind at all if you add an answer yourself. Btw, the [LXC](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/lxc/info) and [LXD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/lxd/info) tags should already give a hint about this.